# Why running the same script with sh and ./ providing return diffent output

Tags: command-line

Contents of `emp1.sh` script

```bash
#!/bin/bash
#emp1.sh: interactive version uses read to take input

echo "Enter the pattern to be searched: \c"
read pname
echo "Enter the file to be used: \c"
read flname
echo "searching for the pattern $pname from the file $flname"
grep "$pname" $flname
echo "Selected records are shown above"
```

Why there is a difference between the outputs?

```
$ sh emp1.sh
Enter the pattern to be searched: 
$ ./emp1.sh
Enter the pattern to be searched: \c
```

Comment: That script is wrong both as an sh-script and as a bash-script. As an sh script, `printf` should be used instead of `echo`. As a bash script, `read`'s -p should be used instead of `echo`. E.g.  `read -ep "Enter file to be used: " flname`

Answer (score 5):

There are two different shells in fact. One is `/bin/bash` and other is `/bin/dash`. And `/bin/sh` is actually a softlink of `/bin/dash`. To verify it, write in terminal,

```
which sh
```

you will get output: `/bin/sh`

Next type `ls -l /bin/sh` in terminal, which will return something like,

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 May 16 20:23 /bin/sh -> dash
```

Which shows the fact that `sh` is a softlink of `/bin/dash`. you can try further `which dash`.

Actually `bash` is `sh` with more features and better syntax. Both of them have almost same commands, but they are different.

**What is happening here**

When you are running `sh emp1.sh` then script is handled by `dash` but when you run `./emp1.sh` due to the shebang line(`#!/bin/bash`) on top of the script `bash` shell handles it. So you get slight different formatting in output. Keep in mind `bash` has some improved syntax.

Answer (score -1):

The output is different because you are using two different programs.

In the first case `sh emp1.sh` you start a program named `sh` and tell it to execute the instructions in emp1.sh. That program sh is probably the bourne shell (sh), a bourne **again** shell (bash) trying to emulate the classic shell (and thus reacting differently from its native mode), dash or even anything else.

When you use `./emp1.sh` you try to execute the script empt1.sh itself. Its first line contains a shebang and an interpreter (`#!/bin/bash`) telling it that it needs to use bash (and all its features).

That means you use a different program/mode than in the first case. And you get different output.

To verify this, try one of these two:

- `/bin/bash emp1.sh`  (which should produce the same output as the ./emp1.sh)
- Or change the first line to `#!/bin/sh`.

Comment: `/bin/sh` is a POSIX shell in modern UNIX and UNIX-like systems. You luckily don't see bourne as `/bin/sh` much anymore. In the case of Ubuntu, dash is used as sh by default.